# Assigning ancillary value to UIButton via KVC

Tags: uibutton, kvc

How can I assign ancillary info to a UIButton?  
Is it possible to assign a via a KVC technique:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSNumber *dateNumb = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:15];
    [self.myButton setValue:dateNumb forKey:@"day"];
}
```

I get the following error doing so:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '... setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key day.'

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do so via the UIButton's layer; not the UIButton itself:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSNumber *dateNumb = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:15];

    CALayer *myLayer = self.myButton.layer;
    [myLayer setValue:dateNumb forKey:@"day"];
      //  [self.myButton setValue:dateNumb forKey:@"day"];
}
```

```
(lldb) po sender.layer
<CALayer:0x7fb5f2819800; position = CGPoint (188 241); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 46 30); delegate = <UIButton: 0x7fb5f281abe0; frame = (165 226; 46 30); opaque = NO; 
autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb5f2819800>>; 
sublayers = (<_UILabelLayer: 0x7fb5f178eba0>); 
allowsGroupOpacity = YES; day = 15>
```